# visual studio 2017 reference errors while loading an c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I am trying to import C# project into my visual studio 2017, and try building it. I am facing this errors regarding references.. when I am trying to get those from Nuget package it is also showing an error above and not able to restore or I am unable to perform any operation

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Debug:Options menu option brings up the Options screen. If you navigate to `NuGet Package Manager`, perhaps checking the `Allow NuGet to download missing..` will resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package source is "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages", which simply does not contain the package that you're trying to download.
Change your package source to nuget.org, the package will be there.

Comment: thanks, it worked....
Just .click on settings and tick mark the nuget.org as package source..

Comment: @sireeshavurrinkala Great! Just mark my answer as the correct one, so others will know what to do